# Is Starkblast a Song of Ice And Fire reference?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, the-dark-tower, reference

In Stephen King's [The Dark Tower: The Wind Through the Keyhole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Tower:_The_Wind_Through_the_Keyhole), there is a storm called the starkblast, which is a very cold wintery storm that comes on very suddenly.

In a George RR Martin's [Song of Ice and Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire), [House Stark's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire_characters#House_Stark) motto is "Winter is Coming".

Is there any hard proof, maybe something from King, that the starkblast is a reference to House Stark/Song of Ice and Fire?

Comment: Stark means strong in German. Could be something in that, maybe.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Highly doubtful.**

The definition of [**stark**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stark) is:

1. having a very plain and often cold or empty appearance
2. unpleasant and difficult to accept or experience
3. very obvious : very plain and easily seen

In short conclusion it is easy to see with the storm King mentions and why GRRM chose the name to represent his northern house independently of each other.

Also, doing some research I have not seen author state their works were influenced by the other. A direct quote would prove me wrong, but I highly doubt there is connection with such a common word.

Comment: Well Stephen King has admitted to being a Harry Potter fan, to the extent that Sneetch-like weapons appear in Wolves of the Calla. So while I agree that in this particular instance it was probably not an homage, Stephen King has been known to insert stuff like that before.